React app error: "you might have mixed up default and named imports"
Error:
index.js:255 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at index.js:258.
    at CustomTopNavBar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:22476:39)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:117861:75)
    at C (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:121146:37)
    at div
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:11914:35)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:40117:31)
    at div
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:11914:35)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:40117:31)
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:29676:1)
    at C (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:121146:37)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:117861:75)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:120601:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:120115:35)
    at AuthRoutes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:29855:5)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:117861:75)
    at Gatekeeper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5983:5)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:117861:75)
    at div
    at CookiesProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:87988:24)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/50.chunk.js:117602:20)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:22935:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:836:1)
CustomTopNavBar @   index.js:255
(anonymous) @   index.js:8
./src/index.js  @   index.js:14
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:856
fn  @   bootstrap:150
1   @   core.js:110
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @   main.chunk.js:1

This is my parent component where I am importing my component CustomTopNavBar:
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import LogoNavbar from "../pages/components/LogoNavbar";
import SideNavBar from "../pages/components/SideNavBar";
import TopNavbar from "../pages/components/TopNavbar";
import { checkRoute } from "../services/routesModify";
import AppContainer from "./AppContainer";
import ROUTES from "./routes";
import IdleTimer from "react-idle-timer";
import { logOut } from "../modules/actions/login.action";
import LogOutWarning from "../pages/components/Modals/LogOutWarning";
import {
  checkUserHasPermission,
  objectHasKeysCheck,
  RenderLazyComponent,
} from "../services/commonMethods";
import { APP_ROUTES } from "../constants/appRoutes";
import Breadcrumbs from "../pages/components/Breadcrumbs";
import CustomTopNavBar from "../pages/components/CustomTopNavBar";

class AuthRoutes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showLogOutWarning: false,
    };

    this.idleTimer = null;
    this.onAction = this._onAction.bind(this);
    this.onActive = this._onActive.bind(this);
    this.onIdle = this._onIdle.bind(this);
    this.idealTimeout = null;
  }

  _onAction(e) {
    localStorage.setItem("userActive", "true");
    // on action method
  }

  _onActive = (e) => {
    if (this.idealTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.idealTimeout);
    }
  };

  _onIdle = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem("userActive", "false");
    this.setState({ showLogOutWarning: true });
    this.idealTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("userActive") === "false") {
        localStorage.removeItem("userActive");
        this.props.logout();
      }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
  };

  render() {
    const { collapseSidebar } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router>
        <AppContainer>
          <IdleTimer
            ref={(ref) => {
              this.idleTimer = ref;
            }}
            events={[
              "keydown",
              "DOMMouseScroll",
              "mousedown",
              "touchstart",
              "touchmove",
              "MSPointerDown",
              "MSPointerMove",
            ]}
            element={document}
            onActive={this.onActive}
            onIdle={this.onIdle}
            onAction={this.onAction}
            debounce={250}
            timeout={1000 * 60 * 25}
          />

          <Grid container className="auth-container">
            <Grid
              item
              lg={collapseSidebar ? 1 : 2}
              className={
                collapseSidebar ? "navbar-collapse" : "navbar-container"
              }
            >
              <LogoNavbar company={this.props.me.Company} />
              <SideNavBar />
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              lg={collapseSidebar ? 11 : 10}
              className={
                collapseSidebar
                  ? "expand-component-container"
                  : "component-container"
              }
            >
              <CustomTopNavBar />
              <div className="content">
                {objectHasKeysCheck(this.props.me) && (
                  <Switch>
                    {ROUTES.map((route, index) => {
                      return checkRoute(route) ? (
                        <Route
                          path={route.route}
                          component={RenderLazyComponent(
                            route.component,
                            this.updateBreadcrumbData
                          )}
                          key={index}
                          exact
                        />
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      );
                    })}
                    <Redirect
                      from={APP_ROUTES.HOME}
                      to={APP_ROUTES.ORDERS}
                    />
                  </Switch>
                )}
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {this.state.showLogOutWarning ? (
            <LogOutWarning
              open={this.state.showLogOutWarning}
              onClose={() => this.setState({ showLogOutWarning: false })}
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </AppContainer>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  collapseSidebar: state.collapseSidebarReducer.collapseSidebar,
  me: state.meReducer.data,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  logout: () => dispatch(logOut()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthRoutes);

Another file:
import { MenuItem, IconButton, Menu } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector, connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { checkShowModal } from "../../../modules/actions/cancelConfirm.action";
import { BootstrapTooltip } from "../ActionColumn";
import { resetMe } from "../../../modules/actions/me.action";
import {
  objectHasKeysCheck,
  userIsProductPartner,
} from "../../../services/commonMethods";
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";
import { DESC } from "../../../constants";
import RealTimeNotifications from "../RealTimeNotification";
import { requestNotifications } from "../../../modules/actions/notifications.action";
import { initializePayloadMethod } from "../../../services/apiRequestMethods";
import ReactWebSocket from "../ReactWebSocket";
import { ENV_CONFIG, NOTIFICATION_TYPES_KEY } from "../../../constants";
import { requestRefillList } from "../../../modules/actions/refillList.action";
import { requestVMList } from "../../../modules/actions/vmList.action";
import NotificationContainer from "../NotificationContainer";
import List from "../../../assets/icons/List.svg";
import Profile from "../../../assets/icons/new-profile-icon.svg";
import Norification from "../../../assets/icons/new-notification-icon.svg";
import Envelope from "../../../assets/icons/Envelope.svg";
import UserIcon from "../../../assets/icons/user.svg";
import Key from "../../../assets/icons/Key.svg";
import { collapseSidebar } from "../../../modules/actions/collapseSidebar.action";
import { logOut } from "../../../modules/actions/login.action";
import Logout from "../../../assets/icons/log-out.svg";

function CustomTopNavBar(props) {
  const notificationIsAllowed =
    props.me.Role && !userIsProductPartner.call({ props });
  const dispatchActions = useDispatch();
  const [notifyObj, setNotifyObj] = useState({});
  const state = useSelector((state) => state.cancelConfirmReducer);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const me = useSelector((state) => state.meReducer.data);
  const notifications = useSelector((state) => state.notificationsReducer.list);
  const [anchorElNotification, setAnchorElNotification] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClickProfile = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleCloseNotification = () => {
    setAnchorElNotification(null);
  };

 

  const handleClickNotification = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNotification(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const onMessageReceived = (result) => {
    // console.log(result);
    try {
      let data = JSON.parse(result);
      setNotifyObj(data);

      //If real time notification and user is on refill list page, refresh the list
      if (
        props.history.location.pathname === "/refills" &&
        data.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES_KEY.REFILL_EXECUTE
      ) {
        props.requestRefillList(
          "/refill-management",
          initializePayloadMethod(
            "list.refills",
            { vending_machine_id: props.refillListPayload.vending_machine_id },
            props.refillListPayload
          )
        );
      }
      //If real time notification and user is on VM list page, refresh the list
      if (
        props.history.location.pathname === "/vm" &&
        data.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES_KEY.VM_STATUS
      ) {
        props.requestVMList(
          "/vending-machine-management",
          initializePayloadMethod(
            "list.active_vending_machines",
            {},
            props.vmListPayload
          )
        );
      }
      dispatchActions(
        requestNotifications("/notification-service", {
          payload: {
            action: "list.notifications",
            sortBy: "created_at",
            sortDir: DESC.toUpperCase(),
            limit: 10,
            offset: 0,
          },
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err in receiving msg", err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="dash-header"
        style={{
          margin: "0px 0px 0px 5px",
          width: "calc(100% - 8px)",
        }}
      >
        <div className="left-header">
          <ul>
            <IconButton classes={{ root: "list-icon" }}>
              <img
                onClick={() => dispatchActions(collapseSidebar())}
                src={List}
                alt="List Icon Image"
                className="list-image"
              />
            </IconButton>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="right-header">
          <ul>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <span>
                <BootstrapTooltip
                  title="Notifications"
                  placement="bottom"
                  onClick={() => props.history.push("/notifications")}
                >
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="slide"
                    classes={{ root: "slide-btn" }}
                    onClick={handleClickNotification}
                  >
                    <img src={Norification} alt="slide-btn" />
                  </IconButton>
                </BootstrapTooltip>
                <Menu
                  id="simple-menu-notification"
                  anchorEl={anchorElNotification}
                  keepMounted
                  open={Boolean(anchorElNotification)}
                  onClose={handleCloseNotification}
                  className="menu-item"
                >
                  <h4 className="notification-title">Notifications</h4>
                  {notifications.slice(0, 5).map((notification) => {
                    return (
                      <MenuItem key={notification.id}>
                        <NotificationContainer data={notification} />
                      </MenuItem>
                    );
                  })}
                  {notifications.length === 0 ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        padding: "20px",
                        fontWeight: "500",
                        marginBottom: "0",
                        fontSize: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      No Notifications Available
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}

                  <p
                    className="view-all-button"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleCloseNotification();
                      props.history.push("/notifications");
                    }}
                  >
                    View all Notifications
                  </p>
                </Menu>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
           
              {objectHasKeysCheck(me) ? (
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="slide"
                  classes={{ root: "slide-btn2 btn-dropdown" }}
                  onClick={handleClickProfile}
                  style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
                >
                  <img src={Profile} alt="slide-btn" />{" "}
                </IconButton>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
              <Menu
                id="simple-menu-notification"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
                className="menu-item menu-item-profile"
              >
                <MenuItem>
                  <img src={Key} alt="slide-btn" />{" "}
                  <span className="ellipsis user-profile-card__company-name ">
                    {props.me.Company
                      ? props.me.Company.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()
                      : ""}
                  </span>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                  <img src={Envelope} alt="slide-btn" />
                  {props.me.email}
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                  <span>
                    <img src={UserIcon} alt="slide-btn" />{" "}
                    {props.me?.Role?.name}
                  </span>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem
                  onClick={() => {
                    dispatchActions(resetMe());
                    dispatchActions(logOut());
                  }}
                >
                  <span>
                    <img src={Logout} alt="slide-btn" /> Logout
                  </span>
                </MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      {notificationIsAllowed && (
        <ReactWebSocket
          url={ENV_CONFIG.notificationWebSocketUrl}
          onMessage={onMessageReceived}
        />
      )}
      <ReactNotification />
      {notifyObj && objectHasKeysCheck(notifyObj) ? (
        <RealTimeNotifications
          data={notifyObj}
          onRemoval={() => setNotifyObj({})}
        />
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  refillListPayload: state.refillListReducer.payload,
  vmListPayload: state.vmListReducer.others,
  me: state.meReducer.data,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  requestRefillList: (urlEndPoint, payload) =>
    dispatch(requestRefillList(urlEndPoint, payload)),
  requestVMList: (urlEndPoint, payload) =>
    dispatch(requestVMList(urlEndPoint, payload)),
});

export default withRouter(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomTopNavBar)
);

I have tried everything but nothing is working for me.

Does the error provide any more information, like in which file you have in import issue? It usually tells you to check the body of a specific component/function/etc. Can you [edit] to provide us the complete error message and any accompany stacktrace?

sir, i have provided more information as you said

I have tidied this post up. There is a second file, which for now I have marked as "Another file". Please make an edit to explain what this file is. Take care to use correct spacing and spelling if you can - Stack Overflow is curated, and is not a chatroom.

So CustomTopNavBar certainly appears to use a default export, and this matches the default import. What can also happen here is that there is an issue creating and exporting CustomTopNavBar, you may need to check all that CustomTopNavBar is importing and rendering. Comment out everything CustomTopNavBar renders and render some simple text to test, if that is ok, uncomment one component/element at-a-time until you see the issue reproduce, then repeat this process in that component/element until you find the culprit code.

than you sir, these two lines cause the error
(1)import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";
(2)
❗ ❗ ❗ As of version 3.3.0 react-notifications-component no longer uses default export. Rely on this import instead
import { ReactNotifications, Store } from 'react-notifications-component'
